# Ubuntu switch java version but that stuck old version

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm a student. I want to learn to command line Linux but I have some issues on the server amazon ubuntu. I need help.

I want swit java version 11 to java version 8 it's confuse

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ubuntu@ip-172-31-72-73:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
ubuntu@ip-172-31-72-73:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

preliminary,I follow this link https://vitux.com/how-to-setup-java_home-path-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Install SDKMAN (https://sdkman.io/install), then use SDKMAN to install JDK, MAVEN, GRADLE.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java , `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`. `sudo update-alternatives --config java`